Using of elastic tangent for structural nonlinear solver
I noticed that some finite element programs, such as Plaxis, do not require the constitutive law to return the consistent tangent, but elastic tangent seems to be sufficient. In my experience, using elastic tangent would lead to very poor convergence, even non-convergence, when materials approach the failure state. I wonder what kind of techniques these software used to stabilize the solution in such a condition.
